# HTML,CSS - Print page doesn't display correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, styles

I really need to optimize this page (http://filipcz.ideatech.cz/mproj/components/tisk.php) for printing on a paper (standard A4 paper size). My page works quite good in Chrome, IE or Edge, but Firefox displays it badly.[image: The image describing my issue]

//Edit: Trying to describe clearer, what I really need to achive: I replaced `<i>Střední průmyslová škola Edvarda Beneše<br>a Obchodní akademie Břeclav</i>`  with `Some text on the left` and `<i>Seznam projektů</i>` with `Text on the right side`.

Code:

```
...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Databáze maturitních projektů</title>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; }
    @media print{
        .netisk{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
    </style>
...

...
    <div align="center" class="netisk">
        <input type="button" value="Vytisknout" onclick="window.print();">
        <input type="button" value="Zavřít okno" onclick="window.close();">
        <hr style="width:30%;">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <i>Some text on the left</i>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <i>Text on the right side</i>
    </div>
    <hr style="width:100%;">
    <div align="center">

<table cellspacing='0'><thead><tr><th> ID </th><th> Název projektu </th><th> Kategorie </th><th> Autor </th><th> Třída </th><th> Rok </th><th> Vedoucí práce </th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>Databáze projektů (PHP + MySQL)</td><td>Webové stránky</td><td>Filip Krolop</td><td>EL 4.A</td><td>2015/2016</td><td>zavodny</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Vytvoření jednoduchého herníhu prostředí v Unreal Enginu 4</td><td>Unity</td><td>Viktor Krčma</td><td>EL 4.A</td><td>2015/2016</td><td>kotlarik</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Návrh podnikové sítě a její simulace v Packet tracer</td><td>Sítě</td><td>Michal Kubík</td><td>EL 4.A</td><td>2015/2016</td><td>kotlarik</td></tr></tbody></table>
    </div>
...
```

Is there any way to fix this using CSS or HTML?

Thank You very much for any help.

Comment: This is a bad code my friend, I don't know what are you trying to achieve? just remove the floats, and put proper html tags, <html>&<body> tags are missing.

Comment: I need to get the same look as it is on the picture in my question (for the right case - in Chrome). When I remove all floats, that text "Seznam projektů" will be on the LEFT side UNDER <i>Střední průmyslová škola Edvarda Beneše<br>a Obchodní akademie Břeclav</i>, which is wrong for me. I need to have this text ""Seznam projektů" on the right side on the same line as <i>Střední průmyslová škola Edvarda Beneše<br>a Obchodní akademie Břeclav</i>. Did I write it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I only removed the floats & added HTML, head & body tags

```
<html>  
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <title>Databáze maturitních projektů</title>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    td { padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div align="center" class="netisk">
    <input type="button" value="Vytisknout" onclick="window.print();">
    <input type="button" value="Zavřít okno" onclick="window.close();">
    <hr style="width:30%;">
</div>
<div>
    <i>Střední průmyslová škola Edvarda Beneše<br>
    a Obchodní akademie Břeclav</i>
</div>
<div>
    <i>Seznam projektů</i>
</div>
<hr style="width:100%;">
<div align="center">

 <table cellspacing='0'><thead><tr><th> ID </th><th> Název projektu </th>     <th> Kategorie </th><th> Autor </th><th> Třída </th><th> Rok </th><th> Vedoucí    práce </th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>Databáze projektů (PHP + MySQL)</td><td>Webové stránky</td><td>Filip Krolop</td><td>EL 4.A</td><td>2015/2016</td><td>zavodny</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Vytvoření jednoduchého herníhu prostředí v Unreal Enginu 4</td><td>Unity</td><td>Viktor Krčma</td><td>EL 4.A</td><td>2015/2016</td><td>kotlarik</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Návrh podnikové sítě a její simulace v Packet tracer</td><td>Sítě</td><td>Michal Kubík</td><td>EL 4.A</td><td>2015/2016</td><td>kotlarik</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

if you want this to show to the right, just change this in the code. I put "Seznam projektů" in the same div and floated it to the right

```
    <div>
    <i>Střední průmyslová škola Edvarda Beneše<br>
    a Obchodní akademie Břeclav</i>
     <i style="float:right">Seznam projektů</i>
     </div>
```

Comment: Well, I need this

<div>
    <i>Seznam projektů</i>
</div>

on the right side

Comment: @FilipCZ you are welcome, I really recommend learning Bootrap specially for starters, it's easy and you can achieve a lot with minimal code and minimal knowledge, please google it Bootstrap CSS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try float left on the broken div.

Comment: I tried to play with 'float', but without success, but thank you for your fast reaction. Any other ideas ppl?

Answer (score 0):

remove the float:left from the left div, and add inline-block to the following  divs.
this works for chrome and firefox.

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <i>Střední průmyslová škola Edvarda Beneše<br>
    a Obchodní akademie Břeclav</i>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; float:right">
    <i>Seznam projektů</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, partially fixed, but still problem with right heading (laying on the <hr> line, but I need it above it).

Comment: are you sure you havent forgotten to remove the floating:right?
this is how i see it http://imgur.com/USrkBRu

Comment: well, but I need to keep that float:right. That text must be on the right side (on the same line as that text on the left).

Comment: uh! missed that, edited original comment accordingly